# Vue.js - Add Class on Click Event

Tags: javascript, css, events, onclick, vue.js

I would like to dynamically toggle a class on a `click` event on a div in Vue.js without using properties/data to do so.

Here is my div

`<div class="quiz-item" @click="checkAnswer(1)">`

When this `div` is clicked, I would like to add the class `quiz-item--correct` or `quiz-item--incorrect` (the logic for this will be handled elsewhere). I cannot use properties as there are too many answers in the quiz for it to be a maintainable/viable approach.

Does anyone have any ideas on how I can achieve this functionality?

Answer (score 23, accepted):

You can do something like this:

```
<div class="quiz-item" @click="$event.target.classList.toggle('classname')">
```

You can check the fiddle demonstrating this:  [**Here**](https://jsfiddle.net/trxvqshv/)

Comment: i dont think classList is supported by all browsers, specifically IE

Comment: @victor Yeah, IE < 10 does not support the `classList` method. But you can use workaround if you want to support those browsers, like calling a function and manipulating classes there.

Comment: Hmm... kinda works... but sadly it didn't for me... Right now when in the div with this listener there is a span or another div or something. When I click on the element the child gets the open class. Not the element itself...

Comment: @LarsVandeDonk If you've nested elements within `div` which can receive clicks you might want to change the click handler to `$event.currentTarget.class...`. The `target` refers to the element where the event occurred which in your case can be any child element, `currentTarget` will refer to element where the event handler is bound. Hope this helps you.